# Page contents not showing on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

What kind of WordPress function do you use to show the page contents?

```
I used the_content to show the post contents, but what about the page contents?
```

I have tried everything, but I haven't found a function that displays the page contents of WordPress.

Also, I have created a basic page.php file, and in the file I have:

```
 <div id="pages">
    <li><?php wp_list_pages() ?></li>
 </div>

Now, why do my index.php have my list of pages even though I didn't use the inlcude  or require function?
```

Keep in mind I created my own theme and site, and I'm trying to put it in WordPress for the first time.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `wp_list_pages()` lists all the pages. If you want to list all the recent posts you should use

**index.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); // If you have sidebar ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**page.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); // If you have sidebar ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Make sure you check the default `twentyeleven` and `twentyten` themes to get idea of how to code WordPress Themes.